# tracking site searches in google analytics

Tags: search, analytics

In google analytics, you can track site searches by setting the query parameter. 
EE does not have search result URLs with a query parameter in them though i.e. search result URLs look like http://mysite.com/search/270ab420bad324607c6286bf28767910/ instead of http://mysite.com/search?q=keyword

So is there an easy way to track site searches using the native EE search module in google analytics - either natively (ideally) or using an add-on? I want to keep using the native EE search module if at all possible.

From searching I've seen various code snippets altering the _gaq.push(['_trackPageview' line in the analytics code, but I'm not sure exactly how to implement this and would rather not mess up the main site tracking, so I was hoping someone may have some working code for this.

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have a [comment in the Search module docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/search/results.html#9402) on this. Inside your Analytics tracking code block, you can do something like this (change the segment conditionals to match your specific case)

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']{if segment_1 == 'search' && segment_2 == 'results'}, ['/search/results/?q={exp:search:keywords}']{/if});
```

Comment: brilliant derek many thanks - my googling had not thrown that up, don't know why i hadn't thought of checking the docs for this!

Answer (score 4):

**"Super search"** supports human-readable ( and therefor analytics-friendly ) queries:
http://www.solspace.com/docs/addon/c/Super_Search

Comment: Thanks Janvl - I should have said that I need to stick with the standard EE search module here - I've updated my question with that info.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible, but you need to modify the GA tracking code on EE's search results template.

There is a wiki article on how to do this, but with the launch of the new Ellis Lab site  you'll have have to take a look at Google's cached version.

[read the cached wiki article](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ahm-mJsFarL8J%3aexpressionengine.com/wiki/Google_Analytics_Site_Search%20google%20analytics%20track%20ee%20search&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=safari)

**UPDATE:** Here's a link to a [Gist of the same article](https://gist.github.com/4165858) in case the wiki doesn't make it back online

Comment: thanks for this mjr and for going to the trouble of digging up the cached link.

Comment: good call on the gist

Answer (score 1):

EE does have native search keyword logging. Here's a link to the [info in the docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/tools/logs/search_log.html).

Comment: No worries. I had a hunch that wasn't the URL you were aiming for. :)