# Search query string in URL (EE 3.x) for Google Analytics

Tags: search, analytics, google-analytics

I've read [tracking site searches in google analytics](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/368/tracking-site-searches-in-google-analytics) but this seems to be "old" - for ExpressionEngine 2.x and an outdated version of the Google Analytics tracking code.

Does anyone know if this is possible in ExpressionEngine 3.x and the latest version of the tracking code?

I've got Analytics code in the `<head>` section of my document:

```
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXXX-X"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXXX-X');
    </script>
```

The search results page on my website has a URL in the following format: `https://www.example.com/search/results/3b335fc51cae38c09d972f1698eb7d84/`

So I'm trying to get the query strings recorded in Analytics as per the original question I've linked to. But using ExpressionEngine 3.x and the current tracking code.

Any advice would be appreciated.